# Facebook eliminate country code from phone number and then ask for verification?

Tags: facebook, verification

Basically, facebook suddenly asks for verification.

However, they eliminate the country code from the verification.

[image]

One obvious explanation is that the guy do not put the country code in his phone on file in facebook.

However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

If the guy click forget password, facebook does know his real phone number complete with country code.

[image]

So if he uses forget password feature, facebook  knows his phone number starts with +62

And yes he's getting SMS at that number and can change his password. However, he cannot confirm his identity.

That's because when confirmin his identity the phone on file is 0816-xxx-xxxx instead of +62816-xxx-xxxx

Anyone else have this problem?

Is this common?

Is he permanently banned and this is how facebook do it? They requires security check that they know cannot be passed because they put wrong number?

Is this a bug?

How do I tell facebook about this?

I reported this several time to facebook and no response whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

I finally can get in.

Facebook always know the true phone number with all the country code. It simply doesn't display it.

For some reason I do not get the message.

Then I try to login to stackexchange with my facebook account. Then I got the same problem. I moved on.

Then I look at my phone. There is an sms from facebook.

I tried to login again and uses that number. It seems that the number never changes.

I managed to get in and have to supply pictures.

I tried to post something on some group and I am in trouble again.

Very strange.

There is no way to talk to facebook representative about this. All efforts to ask them is never answered.

If I had lost my phone and stuff I would have lost access to my facebook account forever.